# magento 2.3 product hide and category hide for guest customer

Tags: product, magento2.3, category, login

i am using magento 2.3 and i want to `products` and `category` hide , if customer not login means i want to hide product and category page hide for guest customer and must be redirect to login page

Answer (score 0):

You can write on `breadcrumb.phtml` page By Objectmanager like this :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$request = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   if($request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view' || $request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
        $url = $block->getBaseUrl().'customer/account/';
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
}
```